# Android viewport scaling

Tags: android, zooming, viewport

I'm a Safari developer and I pretty much ignore IE. That said, I want to support other standards-compliant browsers on other devices like android.

I have a web app that works beautifully on Mac, iPhone, iPad ... but in Android emulator when it's loaded it's zoomed in about 1/2 way.

Is there a magic, silver-bullet answer here that will make this work?

Here's what works beautifully on iPhone and iPad:

```
Add_Meta( 'viewport', 'width=1024, user-scalable=no' )
```

I'm using 1024 because the site was designed that way for computer browser width and iOS seems to have no problem scaling it perfectly. I don't want users to zoom in or out.

Comment: Don't want users to be able to zoom in or out, or don't want them to have to?  The second is fine, the first is not a good goal-  I zoome in on almost everything because I just can't freaking see it, reading at default zoom hurts my eyes.

Comment: I've built the app and device-spcific CSS that would make zooming a problem, not a solution.

Comment: Then you misdesigned your site-  the purpose of HTML and CSS is to *NOT* do that.